# A non discrete, torsion-free and $\sigma-$compact, locally compact abelian group?

Tags: topological-groups

We know that every countable, discrete torsion-free group is $\sigma-$compact. Is there a non discrete, torsion-free, $\sigma-$compact, locally compact abelian group?

Comment: A compact example: the $p$-adic integers for any prime $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\mathbb{R}$, with addition.

Answer (score 0):

Both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{S^1}$ come to mind.

Edit: just kidding.  Only $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $S^1$ is not torsion-free

Comment: Haha, yes indeed.